# MAUI application shows the telemetry log as XAMARIN APP

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin.forms, maui

Currently working on migrating the Xamarin form app to MAUI.
The app gets freezed after executing to certain level. the app gets freezed before launching the first page in the app.
We have changed all reference of Xamarin to MAUI.
Yet the telementry log in the build output shows the Xamarin app : true.

[TelemetryLoggerImpl] {"MAM_APP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION":33,"DEVICE_SDK_PREVIEW_INT":0,"WAS_LAUNCHED":true,"IS_XAMARIN_APP":true,"DEVICE_SDK_INT":31,"DEVICE_CPU_ABIS":"arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi","MAM_APP_ID":"jp.co.cegb.archxtractPush","MAM_APP_MIN_SDK_VERSION":29,"MAM_APP_VERSION":"2.0.3","EVENT_CLASS":"com.microsoft.intune.mam.client.telemetry.events.AppInfoEvent","DEVICE_BRAND":"Sony"}

The only Xamarin references used are the

```
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Common">
    <Version>120.3.3.1</Version>
</PackageReference>

<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Config">
    <Version>121.4.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Firebase.Iid">
    <Version>121.1.0.10</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base">
    <Version>118.2.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement">
    <Version>118.2.0.2</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm">
    <Version>117.0.0.10</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks">
    <Version>118.0.2.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
```

Can these be used in Xamarin apps or is there any alternatives used?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: I see the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18124) you reported, you can check back later to see if there has been any progress.